# Add int to date SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, int

I have a table **Scadenziario** with many columns.

I want to add the column **"Frequenza"**(INT) to the column **"preavviso"** (DATE).

With the query

```
select ID, Scadenza, Frequenza
FROM scadenziario
WHERE Scadenza < '2018-12-11'
```

I'm going to select the row that i need

"**frequenza**" is an int that specify the number of day that will pass before renew the deadline ("**scadenza**")

How can i add "**frequenza**" to "**Scadenza**"?

For example

```
ID | Scadenza  | Frequenza
1  | 2018-12-1 | 20
2  | 2018-1-1  | 40
```

should become

```
ID | Scadenza   | Frequenza
1  | 2018-12-21 | 20
2  | 2018-2-11  | 40
```

Comment: what do you mean (wdum ) by add the column int to date??

Comment: And, what, pray, is the result of adding 13 to the 11th December 2018 meant to *be*? Are you trying to add *days*? *months*? *years*? *hours*? Something else entirely? Also, please add a tag for your RDBMS since not all systems follow the SQL standard for date manipulation.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date function are often very vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: `SELECT Scadenza + INTERVAL Frequenza DAY`

Comment: @SalmanA, the obvious choice... Which MySQL versions support that syntax?

Comment: @jarlh I remember using it 11 years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATE_ADD()` function:

```
select ID, Scadenza, Frequenza, DATE_ADD( Scadenza, INTERVAL Frequenza DAY) 
FROM scadenziario
WHERE Scadenza < '2018-12-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you exactly what to do.
But if I understand correctly this is what you need to do:

```
ALTER TABLE `scadenziario` 
ADD COLUMN `Frequenza ` INT NULL AFTER `scadenza `;
```

Comment: that's not what i need, i edited my question with more information